# How to monitor changes in webview document title with react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, onchange

I basically try to call a function in react native as soon as the document title in my webview changes. I already get the document.title of the web page that is shown in my webview by using this code:

```
  handleMessage(message) {
    alert(message.nativeEvent.data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: "https://website.com/" }}
        injectedJavaScript="window.postMessage(document.title)"
        onMessage={this.handleMessage}
      />
    )
  }
```

Now I want to monitor the title for changes and call a function as soon as this happens. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came here looking for a solution to the same problem but couldn't find one on stackoverflow. My exact requirement was to read the title from WebView and update it on a text box somewhere else and this is how I solved it,

My injected javascript monitors changes in the URL within WebView and calls `postMessage` whenever there is a change.

Here is my injected script:

```
window.currentloc = location.href;
setInterval(function() {
    if (window.currentloc != location.href) {
        window.currentloc = location.href;
        window.postMessage('$#doctitle-' + document.title);
    }
}, 500);
```

I also prefixed my message with `$#doctitle-` to avoid processing all messages coming from my WebView.

My component looks like this:

```
<WebView
     ref={r => (this.webview = r)}
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
     injectedJavaScript="window.currentloc = location.href;setInterval(function() {if (window.currentloc != location.href) {window.currentloc = location.href;window.postMessage('$#doctitle-' + document.title);}}, 500);"
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     onMessage={this.handleMessage.bind(this)}
     onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
     source={{
     uri: 'https://website.com',
   }}
/>
```

My message handler code:

```
handleMessage(event) {
        if(event.nativeEvent.data && event.nativeEvent.data.indexOf("$#doctitle-")==0){
          this.setState({
            windowTitle: event.nativeEvent.data.split('-')[1]
          });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an old topic, but maybe it's gonna help someone.

The first place where we can find title is `onLoadProgress` function. But (at least on Android) it returns previous page title (looks like a bug in library)  - example: let's say there is multistep flow, A -> B -> C -> D, if we progressed from B to C, `onLoadProgress` returns title from B, if we moved back from C to B it's gonna return title from C.

```
export const MyWebView = () => {

    const handleOnLoadProgress = (event) => {
        const {title} = event.nativeEvent;
        console.log('title', title);
    };

    return <WebView
        source={{uri: 'www.google.com'}}
        onLoadProgress={handleOnLoadProgress}
    />;
}
```

There is other solution (copied from @Muthukrishnan answer and enhanced a bit) that utilises `onMessage`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView, WebViewMessageEvent } from 'react-native-webview';

const POLL_FOR_UPDATES = `
  setInterval(function() {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('interval_update');
  }, 2000);
`;

export const MyWebView = () => {

    const handleMessage = (messageEvent: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
        const {title} = messageEvent.nativeEvent;
        console.log('title', title);
    };

    return <WebView
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={POLL_FOR_UPDATES}
        source={{uri: 'www.google.com'}}
        onMessage={handleMessage}
    />;
}
```

Doesn't look best, as there has to be polling in background, but works well.